# YOuTrack workflow fails with one project

Tags: workflow, youtrack

I have written a workflow which ripples down a field to children when it is changed.  This is fine and works well within a project and mainly across projects.  However, there is one particular project for which it fails.

As far as I can tell, the field in the 'bad' project is the same as in others.  The code looks like this

```
issue.links['parent for'].forEach(function(subtask) {
            subtask.fields["Timesheet client"] = issue.fields["Timesheet client"];;
        }
    }
```

The stack trace for the error looks like

```
Processing issue ITP-6:Workflow runtime exception
            jetbrains.youtrack.scripts.wrappers.CustomReferenceFieldValueResolver.set(CustomReferenceFieldValueResolver.java:104)
            org.mozilla.javascript.gen.eqcs_timesheet_coding_change_timesheet_client_3105._c_anonymous_3(eqcs-timesheet-coding/change-timesheet-client:28)
            org.mozilla.javascript.gen.eqcs_timesheet_coding_change_timesheet_client_3105._c_anonymous_2(eqcs-timesheet-coding/change-timesheet-client:24)
```

I can log the part and subtask fields before the assignment and nothing appears wrong with them.

This is YouTrack 2018.2 self-hosted.

Comment: Does the subtask belong to the same project as the parent task? This error may be caused by very different reasons including database corruption. Please create a support request so we could investigate the problem: https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66282.
Also, my first recommendation would be updating your YouTrack to the newer version. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Ana. Mainly the workflow works fine even across projects, but when one particular project is either the parent or child it does not work.  As far as upgrade is concerned we are in the delicate hands of our Infrastructure guys...  I too would like to do this first.

Comment: Sure, please don't hesitate to create a support ticket if the upgrade doesn't help.